# How to uninstall terraform - Windows PC

Tags: uninstall, terraform

I've been looking around on multiple sites on "how to uninstall Hashicorp's Terraform" and I only get back - "Install" results.
Does anyone have info on this?

I did look on Hashicorps' site but there is no easy search function there (there is none).
I cannot find 'uninstall' information anywhere and I definitely do not see that on hashicorp's site.

Do I have to just search through my registry and delete all terraform keys?
I'm logged in as Admin
Win 10 PC with all the latest Windows updates as of Jul 31.
I do not wish to upgrade from 0.11.11 to 0.12.  I just want to do an uninstall like we do for other software.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is late, but I just found question while having the same problem so posting what I did

When you install terraform you do 2 things:

1. Unzip to local directory (Eg C:/Terraform) (zip downloaded from terraform site, containing terraform.exe)
2. Update environment variable to point to that directory

So if you want to upgrade/downgrade to a specific version.

1. Then just download that specific version zip from terraform official
2. Extract and replace that file in local directory (Eg C:/Terraform), that you initially used

If you dont remember the initial directory/local directory then just go yo your environment variables to check path.

Comment: Thanks Sunny.  I will keep this one in mind for upgrading/downgrading.  But Raj yadav's answer is the better one.

Answer (score -1):

For windows machines, open PowerShell and run as an administrator. Install Chocolatey using pip if it is not already there. Then run `choco uninstall terraform`.

Answer (score -2):

Just install the chocolatey package manager, and fire the command `choco uninstall terraform`.

Comment: Hmmm, Raj, I must have missed your posting.  Thanks for the info, that sounds very viable - now I'm ticked I did not think of that one....  esp. since I have Chocolatey...!!   aarrgghhh.

Comment: @gudguy1a Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)